# substr_count and strtolower used together give inconsistent results

Tags: php

I was trying to use substr_count to check the occurrence of a particular string. but this code seems to be giving inconsistent results.

Sometimes it echoes 1 and sometimes 0. I wonder if someone can explain to me why this is happening? Thanks!

```
$val = "hello world ansprüche theme park";
$ne = "ansprüche";
echo substr_count(strtolower($val),$ne);
```

Comment: I always get '1' as the result: https://eval.in/613185

Comment: maybe its PHP version specific? i'm using PHP 5.5.12

Comment: I don't think so. What kind of server does it run on? Is it maybe load balanced?

Comment: running it on wamp server on my local system. i think the flaw is with strtolower as if i use it on $ne too, then it gives '1' everytime.

Comment: I find it better to use `mb_` functions like `mb_strtolower` to avoid problems with multibyte characters

Answer (score 0):

In your string Latin charter **"ansprüche"**. So first you have to Convert a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1.

**Use below code. It's working Fine.**

```
<?php
   $val = "hello world ansprüche theme park hello";
   $ne = "ansprüche";
   echo substr_count(strtolower(utf8_decode($val)), utf8_decode($ne));
?>
```